# How to find all n-grams only within each line of a text file/entry of a csv?

Tags: python, nltk

```
from nltk import *
from collections import Counter

bigtxt = open('toSort.txt', 'r').read()
ngram_counts = Counter(ngrams(bigtxt.split(), 3))


print(ngram_counts.most_common(10))
```

I am working on a dataset where there are multiple entries (where each entry was originally a row in a csv file but is now a line of a text file) of various phrases: Ex.

```
jump top left now 
blue sky time 
wow can see every place
```

The first code portion above is my attempt to find all n-grams of a certain size (in this case 3), but it is treating all the lines in the text file as one continuous run-on phrase (as expected), and thus finding all n-grams even across different lines, giving me, for example:

```
 jump top left 
 top left now
 left now blue
 now blue sky
```

as various 3-grams. What is the best way to only find n-grams within a line and count their frequencies, such that

```
jump top left
top left now
```

are valid 3-grams but

```
now blue sky
```

is not?

Comment: Are you asking how to iterate over the lines in a file?

Comment: Yes, but is there a best way to sort each n-gram after iterating over the lines, as in dictionary versus other structure? Sorry I am new to python.

Answer (score 0):

You can read file line by line, count ngrams separately for each line and then merge counters together:

```
from nltk import *
from collections import Counter

ngram_counts = Counter()
with open('toSort.txt') as bigtxt:
    for l in bigtxt:
        ngram_counts.update(Counter(ngrams(l.split(), 3)))


print(ngram_counts.most_common(10))
```

[Counter.update](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.update):

> Elements are counted from an iterable or added-in from another mapping (or counter). Like dict.update() but adds counts instead of replacing them.